# Camel: UTF-8 Encoding is lost after using Group

Tags: encoding, utf-8, apache-camel, tokenize

I'm using camel 2.14.1 and splitting huge xml file with Chinese/Japanese characters using group=10000 within tokenize tag. 
Files are created successfully based on grouping but Chinese/Japanese text codes are converted to Junk characters.

I tried enforcing UTF-8 before new XML creation using "ConvertBodyTo" but still issue persists.

Can someone help me !!

Comment: one thing i observed was XML Prologue is missing in newly generated files and suspecting this is causing the issue. :S

Comment: Please show your code so far, and check with the [help] for posting guidelines more generally.

Comment: I have added XML Prologue/DTD in my split xml(s) manually using a processor class i.e creating a file in my processor , appending with XML DTD tag and sending the body back

<to uri="file://{{dir.path}}?fileExist=Append&amp;fileName=$simple{property.FileName}-$simple{property.MessageId}.xml&amp;charset=utf-8" />

Comment: The reason you are receiving downvotes and close votes is that your question does not contain the information we need in order to spend useful time on helping you, let alone then solve your problem. Please review the posting guidelines in the [help] and then [edit] your question to provide the missing details.  Typically, your question should be self-contained and include the code you are having trouble with, as well as a sample of the input, the actual output, and the expected output. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had run into a similar issue while trying to split a csv file using tokenize with grouping.

Sample csv file: (with Delimiter - '|')
**CandidateNumber|CandidateLastName|CandidateFirstName|EducationLevel**

CAND123C001|Wells|Jimmy|Bachelor's Degree (±16 years)

CAND123C002|Wells|Tom|Bachelor's Degree (±16 years)

CAND123C003|Wells|James|Bachelor's Degree (±16 years)

CAND123C004|Wells|Tim|Bachelor's Degree (±16 years)

The **±** character is corrupted after tokenize with grouping. I was initially under the assumption that the problem was with not setting the proper File Encoding for split, but the exchange seems to have the right value for property CamelCharsetName=ISO-8859-1.

```
from("file://<dir with csv files>?noop=true&charset=ISO-8859-1")
.split(body().tokenize("\n",2,true)).streaming()
.log("body: ${body}");
```

The same works fine with dont use grouping.

```
from("file://<dir with csv files>?noop=true&charset=ISO-8859-1")
.split(body().tokenize("\n")).streaming()
.log("body: ${body}");
```

Thanks to this post, it confirmed the issue is while grouping.

Looking at [GroupTokenIterator](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/util/GroupTokenIterator.java)  in camel code base the problem seems to be with the way TypeConverter is used to convert String to InputStream

```
// convert to input stream
InputStream is =
camelContext.getTypeConverter().mandatoryConvertTo(InputStream.class, data);
...
```

Note: the *mandatoryConvertTo()* has an overloaded method with exchange

```
<T> T mandatoryConvertTo(Class<T> type, Exchange exchange, Object value)
```

As the exchange is not passed as argument it always falls back to default charset set using system property "org.apache.camel.default.charset"

Potential Fix:

```
// convert to input stream
InputStream is =
camelContext.getTypeConverter().mandatoryConvertTo(InputStream.class, exchange, data);
...
```

As this fix is in the camel-core, another potential option is to use split without grouping and use *AgrregateStrategy* with *completionSize()* and *completionTimeout()*.

Although it would be great to get this fixed in camel-core.